# Using Actinic V8 and having a problem with Path to Perl and Perl Script Extension

Tags: perl, cgi, file-extension, actinic

I am using Actinic v8 and having a problem locating the path to Perl. I am getting this message popping up and I just don't know what to do to solve it.

> The wizard needs to know where Perl is installed on the web server and what extension Perl scripts must have in order to execute on the remote server.  You may need to contact your ISP to gather this information.  Be sure to specify the "." on the extension if it is required.  For example, ".cgi", or ".pl".

It then gives you an option for 'Path to Perl' and 'Perl Script Extension'

Answer (score 0):

Your ISP knows where and if `perl` is installed on your server and if the server is configured to require file extensions for CGI scripts. There is no way anyone else can tell for certain.